# Objects/components to close or delete on the onDestroy callback

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I am still not clear about this point and I did not find really clear explanations: what are the objects/components that should be closed/deleted on the `onDestroy` callbacks?

From what I read, there would be at least:

- listeners to remove
- database handler to close

But are there other things to handle?

Thanks!

Comment: worth mentioning: onDestroy() and onStop() are not guaranteed to be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to explicitly close something only because it's a database handler or a listener. .

You would want to kill the things that you do not need anymore but that can be mistakenly called after onDelete (or onStop) occured.

Those can be: services because thay are likely not  to be killed by OS and thus run while no one needs them. Broadcast receivers because they can get a message from the system and try to process it while your activity is already invalid. Handlers because they can receive messages from other part of your app. Listeners and databases connections because other parts of your app can inadvertently use them while the activity that provides them is already in invalid state.
So, it's a matter of logic what to close in onStop / onDestroy and not a matter of classification.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what you typed. When that callback method occurs then you will want to close any database connections and anything you are listening to, like SMS messages.

You can also delete temp files during that event. Or maybe you want to send an email off as well. It is really whatever you want but the dev docs really recommend that you close DB xnets and Service xnets.

Lazy developers just leave this method empty.